# Change date format from dd/mm/yyy to dd-mm-yyyy

Tags: excel, vba

I have tired to change the date format from `dd/mm/yyyy` to `yyyy-mm-dd`. In the front end users entered the date in `dd/mm/yyyy` format while import the same details to Text file the date format should be printed in `yyyy-mm-dd` format.

```
Range("A1").Value = Format(Range("A1").value, "dd/mm/yyyy")

Range("A1").Value = Format(Range("A1").value, "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

The user has entered the date `dd/mm/yyyy` in Cell A1. While importing the same to Text file it should be printed as `yyyy-mm-dd`

Comment: did you try to use `Cdate` to convert your text to date ?   So you will have this : `Range("A1").Value = CDate(Format(Range("A1").value, "yyyy-mm-dd"))`

Comment: Yes i have use the same, but still shows the date as dd/mm/yyy

Answer (score 1):

You should change the formatting of the cell, too, not just its value:

```
Range("A1").NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
```

Comment: While using the above code i'm getting error."Unable use NumberFormat property at the Range class

Comment: @Anu make sure your sheet is not protected?

Comment: And what does it say, if you type `? Range("A1").NumberFormat` into the Immediate Window?

Comment: I don't need this the date format will be changed only writing the data to text file

Comment: I didn't see your code that prints to a text file but you can add there something like `Format(Range("A1").Value, "yyyy-mm-dd")`.

Answer (score 1):

#### If your date in A1 is a string/text (and not a real date) …

… you cannot use `Format()` which only works on real dates and numbers. Therfore you need to analyze the string and create a real date first:

```
Dim DateString As String
DateString = Range("A1").Value

'split string into 3 parts
Dim DateArr As Variant
DateArr = Split(DateString, "/")

'create a real date out of the 3 parts
Dim RealDate As Date
RealDate = DateSerial(DateArr(2), DateArr(1), DateArr(0))

'write real date into cell
Range("A1").Value = RealDate
'format it in desired format
Range("A1").NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
```

#### If your date in A1 is a real date (not a string) …

… then you can just format your cell

```
Range("A1").NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
```

#### Recommendation

Never use strings for dates. A date has always to be a date format never a string/text. Otherwise you cannot tell if a date is `dd/mm/yyyy` or `mm/dd/yyyy`. String dates are evil!

Comment: @Anu Then just change the number format to `"yyyy-mm-dd"` and that's all. If your date format doesn't change then that means you have no real date but a string/text in that cell. That means you need to convert the string into a real date first (as explained in the first part of my answer).